# Whats wrong with this line of code?

Tags: java, android, xml, button

im getting an error from logcat:

```
 01-13 17:53:25.368: E/AndroidRuntime(3235): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-13 17:53:25.368: E/AndroidRuntime(3235):     at android.app.activity3.onCreate(activity3.java:18)
```

for this piece of code. So somethings wrong with line 18*

```
 Button wg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Back);
        wg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
            }

        });
    }
}
```

This is line 18:

```
wg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

Thankyou!

Comment: Well, `NullPointerException` on `wg.someMethod()` is a hint.

Comment: Yeah, I'm kinda guessing that it didn't find that view.

Comment: Did you forget to set the content view? Is it the correct layout file? is it happening before this code?

Comment: How can it not find the view?

Comment: how do i set the content view?

Comment: @user1148715 With [`Activity#setContentView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView(android.view.View)).

Comment: @Jeffrey where do i place it?

Comment: In the `Activity#onCreate` method, you need to set the content view to your main layout. I suggest you review the [Android tutorials](http://developer.android.com/resources/browser.html?tag=tutorial) since you appear to be missing some basics.

Comment: Are you doing that in your onCreate method? Because that could come of the fact you didn't do a setContentView!

Comment: How do i do it then? @JeremyD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things that could be happening here:

1) You forgot to call the `setContentView()` method in your `onCreate()` method.

2) Your ID `R.id.Back` does not exist in the XML file you loaded with `setContentView()`.

Since you'd see an error in eclipse if the ID was bad, the most likely cause is that you forgot to call the `setContentView(R.layout.some_layout_xml_file)` in the `onCreate()` method of your activity.

Comment: I actually did lol   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main3);

Answer (score 2):

`wg` is null. It appears that `findViewById` is returning null.

Comment: This might be true but how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

NullPointerExceptions are for when you reference an object that doesn't exist, for instance;

```
SomeObject someObj;

public static void main (String[] args) {
    someObj.someMethod();
}
```

Will get you a NullPointerException, where as;

```
SomeObject someObj;

public static void main (String[] args) {
    someObj = new SomeObject();
    someObj.someMethod();
}
```

Will see you ok.